# Owl Carousel 2 issue with loading class

Tags: jquery, carousel, owl-carousel

I've searched quite widely about this but can find no definitive answer, so hoping somebody can help shed some light on this.

When an owl carousel loads, it doesn't know the height, so the boxes flicker and then pop to the size of the image as the plugin reads the size of the images.

To help get around this I originally tried adding some styles of .owl-loading, but no matter what I do none of my styles are applied there, and to be honest I can't even see it appearing on page load.

In an attempt to get around this I tried adding my own custom 'loading' class and then use the onInitialized callback like this:

```
onInitialized: function() {
    $('.loading').removeClass('loading');
}
```

That kind of works, but it fires too early. So I can see my loading class then, plugin initalises then remove my class, the carousel collapses in size then reappears as the images are loaded.

What I would like to do is only have that class removed AFTER the images are loaded, but there doesn't appear to be a callback for that. Any further ideas here?

Answer (score 2):

I do something similar, but I use [lazySizes](http://afarkas.github.io/lazysizes/#examples) to lazyload the active images. You can setup a callback to remove the loading div after lazySizes finishes loading all the active images, but it works fine for me without it.

```
 /**
 * Initialize the carousel. On initialized, hide the spinner and lazyload the images for the active carousel items
 * @param settings
 */
ImageCarousel.prototype.setupOwl = function(settings) {

    var self = this;
    this.owlCarousel = this.el.find('.owl-carousel').on({

        'initialized.owl.carousel': function () {

            self.lazyloadActive();      //lazyload the active carousel items
            self.el.find('#image-carousel__loading').hide();

        }

    }).owlCarousel(settings);

    this.bindEvents();
};

/**
 *  Find the images of the active owl items and add "lazyload" class to load them
 */
ImageCarousel.prototype.lazyloadActive = function() {
    var images = this.el.find('.owl-item.active .image-carousel__image');
    $(images).addClass("lazyload");
};
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, only just saw this! Solution looks solid, I have actually just started using lazysizes in conjunction with owl.carousel too, but this takes it further.